# GOF Composite Design Pattern CompositeObject::Remove Recursive Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, recursion, composite

This is the part of question from my question asked in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website:

[GOF Composite Design Pattern Implementation Using Modern C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67761/gof-composite-design-pattern-implementation-using-modern-c)

The post has complete information/implementation about it but here I am posting this question to understand about the following information:

```
How to implement CompositeEquipment::Remove?.
```

Based on my understanding, it should do recursive search in all composite object in which client has invoked and `recursively all its child objects which can also be of composite type`. Just to illustrate from above implementation, if client write the as `cabinet->Remove(bus)`; it would not remove bus object as it is the child of `chassis` object. This seems to be incorrect to me. However I am not able to implement the `CompositeEquipment::Remove` in such a way that it searches recursively if child objects themselves are of composite.

So far I have came of with the following implementation which just  searches the composite objects which client has involved for `Remove` method.

```
//To find out whether items are in the composite objects
class Name_Equal {
private:
    Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr val;
public:
    Name_Equal(const Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr& v) :val(v) { }
    bool operator()(const Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr& x) const { 
        return (x->Name() == val->Name()); 
    }
};

void CompositeEquipment::Remove(EquipmentSmartPtr entry) {
    find_equipment(_equipment, entry);
}

void CompositeEquipment::find_equipment(std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>& vec, 
    EquipmentSmartPtr& entry){
    Name_Equal eq(entry);
    auto itrpos = std::find_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), eq);
    if (itrpos != std::end(vec)) {
        vec.erase(itrpos);
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know in case any additional information or complete code needs to post here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Provide a `virtual` function `Remove` in the base class and make it a noop implementation. Then add a few more lines to `CompositeEquipment::find_equipment`.

   ```
   void CompositeEquipment::find_equipment(std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>& vec, 
       EquipmentSmartPtr& entry){
       Name_Equal eq(entry);
       auto itrpos = std::find_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), eq);
       if (itrpos != std::end(vec)) {
           vec.erase(itrpos);
       } else {
           for ( EquipmentSmartPtr sptr : vec )
           {
              sptr->Remove(entry);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `dynamic_cast` to determine whether an item of the composite is a composite also. If so, call `Remove` on it. I prefer this option.

   ```
   void CompositeEquipment::find_equipment(std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>& vec, 
       EquipmentSmartPtr& entry){
       Name_Equal eq(entry);
       auto itrpos = std::find_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), eq);
       if (itrpos != std::end(vec)) {
           vec.erase(itrpos);
       } else {
           for ( EquipmentSmartPtr sptr : vec )
           {
              Equipment* ptr = dynamic_cast<Equipment*>(sptr.get());
              if ( ptr )
              {
                 ptr->Remove(entry);
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

A bit about names... `find_equipment` seems a strange name for the function. I would put the whole thing in `Remove`.

```
    void CompositeEquipment::Remove(EquipmentSmartPtr& entry){
        std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>& vec = _equipment;
        Name_Equal eq(entry);
        auto itrpos = std::find_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), eq);
        if (itrpos != std::end(vec)) {
            vec.erase(itrpos);
        } else {
            for ( EquipmentSmartPtr sptr : vec )
            {
               Equipment* ptr = dynamic_cast<Equipment*>(sptr.get());
               if ( ptr )
               {
                  ptr->Remove(entry);
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @R Sahu: Thanks for your explanation on this.By the way virtual function Remove has been defined in base class Component and it deos noop implementation. I hope this is what you were suggesting.

Comment: @R Sahu: Does dynamic_cast is necessary as Remove() take the  EquipmentSmartPtr. So i think it is not required.

Comment: @MantoshKumar, I did not see `Remove()` in the base class. I think it doesn't belong in the base class. The notion of removing an `Equipement` from another `Equipment` does not make sense except for `CompositeEquipment`. But if you decide to keep `Remove()` in the base class, then `dynamic_cast` is not necessary.

Comment: @R Sahu: This is an example taken from motivational section in GOF book. They have mentioned about these points but client should not distinguish between leaf and composite objects. However I got your point and thanks for your input.